# File responses in Python Pyramid 'cancelling' each other out?

Tags: python, httpresponse, pyramid

Here are three Pyramid view_callables which setup a page with data and two image files.  Trouble is, only one of the images (file responses) is returned.  It seems I can only return one of the images at a time.  If I take one of the file response vc's away, the other images is returned.  However, if I have both file respone vc's there, only the second image is returned.  Is there some object in the first vc I'm overwriting with the second vc?

Is there a better way to return both images (files), even within the first `# title` vc?  As it is now, even if it worked, I have to retrieve the same document from the database 3 times for the one template.  Any advice or clues would be greatly appreciated.

```
# title
@view_config(
        route_name='title',
        renderer='templates/titles/title.jinja2')
def title(request):
    title = Title().find_one({'_id':ObjectId(request.matchdict['_id'])})
    result = dict(
            user = request.user,
            title = title)
    return result

# view title image
@view_config(route_name="view_title_image")
def jpg(request):
    fd = Title().find_one({'_id':ObjectId(request.matchdict['title_id'])}).TitleImage
    response = Response(content_type='application/jpg')
    response.app_iter = fd.File
    print fd
    return response

# view trailer thumbnail
@view_config(route_name="view_trailer_thumbnail")
def jpg(request):
    fd = Title().find_one({'_id':ObjectId(request.matchdict['title_id'])}).TrailerThumbnail
    response = Response(content_type='application/jpg')
    response.app_iter = fd.File
    print fd
    return response
```

Here are the route configs from `__init__`:

```
# title
config.add_route('title', '/title/{_id}')

# view title image
config.add_route('view_title_image', '/view/title_image/{title_id}')

# view title image
config.add_route('view_trailer_thumbnail', '/view/trailer_thumbnail/{title_id}')
```

This is how its used in the Jinja2 template:

```
<img src="/view/title_image/{{ title._id }}">

<img src="/view/trailer_thumbnail/{{ title._id }}">
```

Comment: What are the config.add_route() calls?

Comment: Do individual calls to the image give you consistent results? So accessing `/view/title_image/someid` and `/view/title_image/someid` both work, right? Are you running a single-threaded development server? Does switching to a server capable of handling more than one request at a time help?

Comment: @Daniel I've added the config.add_route() calls

Comment: @MartijnPieters, Yes, both work when called alone, but only one works when they are called with the same render.

Comment: @MFB: and you are running this under `pserve`, right? That's a single-threaded setup *only* and your browser may be trying to pipeline requests as well. I suspect the problem lies there..

Comment: @MartijnPieters, pserve yes. I will test this when I'm back in the saddle. Thanks for the clue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that both views have the function named jpg.

Although it's not a great idea to overwrite functions like that, I would have thought that this would be no problem at all for the view_config decorator. The only thing I can think of is that rather recording a reference to the function, view_config works out what the dotted path would be and records that.

Anyway, give the view functions different names and you should be fine.